# SCSS - nth child as a parent?

Tags: css, sass

If i have some code that looks like this:

```
.my-class {
    :nth-child(2) {
      padding-left: 0;
    }
}
```

Where `nth-child(2)` is a `div`,can i then "target" another `div` that has the `some-div` class inside of it?

I tried to do something like this:

```
.my-class {
    :nth-child(2) {
      padding-left: 0;

      .some-div {
        some: style;
      }
    }
}
```

but it didn't work..

Comment: If that didn't work then that means `some-div` doesn't exist, add html to your question, also is the nth-child supposed to be nth child of `my-class` or a div inside of it?

Comment: Yes if the condition is correct it will work; please post all your relevant code so your question can be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you shared your HTML structure, but assuming you are trying to target the child, with class `some-div`, of the 2nd child of the `my-class` element, your code should work just fine.

This:

```
.my-class {
  :nth-child(2) {
    padding-left: 0;
    .some-div {
      color:red;
    }
  }
}
```

Would compile to this:

```
.my-class :nth-child(2) {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.my-class :nth-child(2) .some-div {
  color: red;
}
```

```css
.my-class :nth-child(2) {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.my-class :nth-child(2) .some-div {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-class">
  <div>1.</div>
  <div>2.<div class="some-div">2a.</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You guys are right, i looked at my HTML code wrong.. took me some time to realize, but thanks for pointing out that there should be no problems with this code!

Answer (score 0):

It should work, first check if your parent have `padding-left: 0` - it probably doesn't because you haven't used **&** in `&:nth-child(2)`.

Right now you are generating css `.my-class :nth-child(2) .some-div` (you are looking for element with class *some-div* in second child of element with class *my-class*) not `.my-class:nth-child(2) .some-div`.